# Don't be Greedy

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

this is a cs50 puzzle day 2019 question
as you would know the questions have a one english word answer.

[image: Puzzle 1 is in the picture]

will someone like to collab with me to solve all of them? there are 10 more of them.

Comment: This is from an ongoing contest. While participants are welcome to work on it alone, online with their team, or alongside other teams, Puzzling Stack Exchange is not "your team" and we have a policy that does not accept contest puzzles while the contest is active. For more information see our policy on **[Questions from Ongoing Contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests/1675)**.

Answer (score 3):

## FINANCIER

1. Take the difference between each pair of values
2. Correspond these differences to alphabet letters (exclude 0's)
3. Order the letters by the lowest value in either column in the original table.